# How to connect the Round node to the count socket in the Mesh Line node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a line with a chosen object as an instance on every vertex. As you can see in the picture, I want to control the amount of verticies in that line through the input points on the group input of the modifier. Is there a node which would allow me to convert the rounded value in such a manner that I would be able to connect it into the "Count" socket on the Mesh Line node?

[image]

Comment: The _Count_ input accepts only a single integer value as input, that's why it's round and green. The _Random Value_ node creates a field of (which means multiple) float values. Although you are rounding its output, it's still more than a single value. To get just a single random value, you could enter an integer value in the ID input of the _Random Value_ node. This makes the node output just the one random value which is generated for this ID. Which in this case means, you have kind of two seed values: switching the ID and the seed value gives different random results.

Comment: Yeah, the answer @Chris gave here - which you can also find under the duplicate question. See my answer there to find out more about how the ID and Seed are working to produce different random results which as aforementioned.

Comment: Related: [Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this node setup to get what you want:

[image]

Because the ID is now always the same, the random value is no field value anymore but a constant, that's why it works now.